# How can I stop emojis appearing in Slack message from webhook?

Tags: webhooks, slack-api

I'm using a webhook to post crashes to a Slack channel. I've noticed German flags appearing in the text. This happens when I post a MAC address with `:de:` which is being interpreted as an emoji. How can I declare my text as pure text that shouldn't be interpreted?